# Base class attribute names for templates with no explicit ember view

Tags: ember.js

So in Ember it's awesome that you don't necessarily need to extend a view for a template and instead one can automagically be created for your template.

My question is, for the base HTML element of a templates automagically created view how can I specify a class name so I can namespace the CSS?

```
// template /////////////////
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contacts">
    ...
</script>

// html /////////////////
<div id="ember337" class="ember-view MyCoolClassName">  <---- custom class name in here
   ...
</div>
```

I know I can do it by extending a view for this template but to simply add an additional class name that seems overkill.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that isn't possible, because the root tag of a view, like this:

```
<div id="ember337" class="ember-view MyCoolClassName">
```

is generated from, your properties:

```
   SomeView = Ember.View.create({
     elementId: 'ember337',
     classNames: ['ember-view', 'MyCoolClassName'],
     tagName: 'div'
   });
```

If you don't want to create a view to add a simple class, you can do:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contacts">
  <div class="MyCoolClassName">
    Hello world
  </div>
</script>
```

And in your css:

```
.ember-view .MyCoolClassName {
  /*some style */
}
```

Comment: I see!  Your second option is the perfect solution.  I thought I saw that an outer wrapping div was automatically being created for my viewless templates when in fact it's not, just for my application template.  With your second solution I get my namespace without a "double" div.  Thanks!